# How to store all container's data in docker?

Tags: docker

I am trying to execute ubuntu in docker. I use this command `docker run -it ubuntu`, and I want to install some packages and store some files. I know about volumes, but I have used it only in docker-compose. Is it possible to store all the container's data or how can I do that properly?

Comment: You almost never directly run base images like `ubuntu`; instead you'd use them as a base for your custom image, with a Dockerfile that installs the application you want the container to run.  Have you read background material like Docker's [Build and run your image](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/) tutorial?

Answer (score -1):

when you run a container, Docker creates a namespace and loads the image filesystem in that namespace. any changes you apply in a running container including installing some packages only remains during the lifetime of the container if you remove the container and rerun it they're gone.
if you want to your changes be permanent you have to commit the running container and actually create an image for that using this command:

As David pointed out in the comments

**You should pretty much never run docker commit. It leads to images that can't be reproduced, and you'll be in trouble if there's a security fix you're required to take a year down the road**.

```
sudo docker commit [CONTAINER_ID] [new_image_name]
```

if you have an app inside the container like MySQL and wants the data stored in that app be permanent you should map a volume from the host like this:

```
docker run -d -v /home/username/mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql --name mysql mysql
```

Comment: You should pretty much never run `docker commit`.  It leads to images that can't be reproduced, and you'll be in trouble if there's a security fix you're required to take a year down the road.

Comment: @DavidMaze So if I understood you guys correctly, if I want to run an ubuntu system, I should use other virtual programs, for example, VirtualBox instead of Docker?